# More efficient sql querys

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

These are some of my querys which were working great but now when the table have 5 million rows these querys are talking to much time to load abut 30 sec.

and the memory is allowed to run these is set to 500 mb if i decrees the memory to like 400 mb the page gives error as it run out of memory, these querys are talking so much time and memory.

How can I make these SQL query more efficient?

```
$total_traffic = $db->getAll("SELECT COUNT(`userid`) AS `total_clicks` FROM `".PREFIX."traffic_stats` WHERE `userid` = ?i", $user->data->userid);

$total_earning = $db->getAll("SELECT SUM(`rate`) AS `total_earned` FROM `".PREFIX."traffic_stats` WHERE `userid` = ?i", $user->data->userid);


$today_earning = $db->getAll("SELECT SUM(`rate`) AS `today_earned` FROM `".PREFIX."traffic_stats` WHERE `userid` = ?i AND DATE(from_unixtime(created)) = CURRENT_DATE ORDER BY created DESC", $user->data->userid);

$yesterday_earning = $db->getAll("SELECT SUM(`rate`) AS `yesterday_earned` FROM `".PREFIX."traffic_stats` WHERE `userid` = ?i AND DATE(from_unixtime(created)) = DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE,INTERVAL 1 DAY) ORDER BY created DESC", $user->data->userid);
```

(and the number of rows are expected to grow even more is there any server side recommendations/changes i can get ? )

EDIT :

here are the queries which update the table 

    `$revisit = $db->getRow("SELECT`traffic_id`FROM`".PREFIX."traffic_stats`WHERE`key`= ?s AND`ip_address`= ?s AND`domain` = ?s", $key, $ip, $domain);

```
$traffic_data = array(
  "userid" => $userid,
  "username" => $username,
  "article_id" => $article,
  "key" => $key,
  "domain" => $domain,
  "origin" => $origin,
  "ip_address" => $ip,
  "rate" => $rate,
  "created" => $time
);
if(!$revisit) {
  if(($db->query("INSERT INTO `".PREFIX."traffic_stats` SET ?u", $traffic_data)) && ($id = $db->insertId())) {
    if(($db->query("UPDATE `".PREFIX."articles` SET `viewed` = `viewed` + ?i WHERE `article_id` = ?i", 1, $article)) && ($db->query("UPDATE `".PREFIX."user_stats` SET `clicked` = `clicked` + ?i WHERE `article_id` = ?i AND `key` = ?s", 1, $article, $key))) {
      echo json_encode(array("status" => 1, "url" => $redirect_url, "title" => $get_redirect->article_title, "desc" => $get_redirect->article_desc, "domain" => $track->domain.$key, "base_domain" => $track->domain, "image" => $get_redirect->article_og_image));
    }
  }
```

`
and there are also some for ip geo locations

Comment: What indexes do you have?

Comment: Questions about optimization always require, as a minimum CREATE TABLE statements for all relevant tables, and the results of the EXPLAIN. In addition, see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: One obvious optimization is to reverse the logic, of DATE(from_unixtime(created)) = CURRENT_DATE such that a function is performed on the constant instead of the column

Comment: @Strawberry I edit the question about it, thanks.

Comment: @PM 77-1, i am not sure about it, i think non.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One optimization is to use one query instead of three:

```
SELECT COUNT(userid) total_clicks
     , SUM(rate) total_earned 
     , SUM(CASE WHEN DATE(from_unixtime(created)) = CURRENT_DATE THEN rate END) total_earned_today
     , SUM(CASE WHEN DATE(from_unixtime(created)) = CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 DAY THEN rate END) total_earned_yesterday
  FROM traffic_stats 
 WHERE userid = $userid
```

For further optimizations, see comments above, but here's another thing to think about...

```
SELECT CURDATE();
+------------+
| CURDATE()  |
+------------+
| 2017-01-09 |
+------------+

SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP()/86400)*86400) x 
     , FROM_UNIXTIME(CEILING(UNIX_TIMESTAMP()/86400)*86400) y;
+---------------------+---------------------+
| x                   | y                   |
+---------------------+---------------------+
| 2017-01-09 00:00:00 | 2017-01-10 00:00:00 |
+---------------------+---------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but i need to echo the querys separately at separate places, how i can do that with one one query?

Answer (score 0):

Since all(?) of your queries are based on `userid`, and the table will be very large, it may become desirable to have a clustered `PRIMARY KEY` starting with `userid` and possibly `created`.  I can say more after you provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: @Naby until you respond to my first comment we can have nothing further to add.

Comment: @Naby In which case you must have mis-read or overlooked the accepted answer attached to my original comment.